# Values overwritten with the last iteration in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, list, loops

I have these entities:
Car / Vehicle / Auto / CustomDTO

```
Car
- long carId
Vehicle
- long vehicleId;
Auto
- long autoTypeId;
CustomDTO
- long autoTypeId;
- String autoTypeName;
- List<Car> cars;

public List<Car> getCarByVehicleAndType(long vehicleId, long autoTypeId){
    List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    List<Car> carsInCarVehicleType = carService.getCarsInCarVehicleType(vehicleId, autoTypeId); //DAO Fetch cars IN Cat-Vehicle-Type table
    for(Car car : carsInCarVehicleType){
        car.selected(true);
    }
    List<Car> carsNotInCarVehicleType = carService.getCarsNotInCarVehicleType(vehicleId, autoTypeId); //DAO Fetch cars NOT IN Cat-Vehicle-Type table
    for(Car car : carsNotInCarVehicleType){
        car.selected(false);
    }

    cars.addAll(carsInCarVehicleType);
    cars.addAll(carsNotInCarVehicleType);

    return cars;
}

public List<CustomDTO> constructVehicleDTO(long vehicleId){
    List<Auto> autos = autoService.getAutos(); //DAO Fetch all autos
    List<CustomDTO> dtoList = new ArrayList<CustomDTO>();
    for(Auto auto : autos){
        CustomDTO dto = new CustomDTO();
        dto.setAutoTypeId(auto.getAutoTypeId());
        dto.setAutoTypeName(auto.getAutoTypeName());
        dto.setCars(getCarByVehicleAndType(vehicleId, auto.getAutoTypeId());
        dtoList.add(dto);
    }
    return dtoList;
}
```

In the above method - *`dto.setCars(...)` is  overwritten with the last iteration values when dtoList is returned*. So for every Car I am getting the same set of Car List. This wont happen in plain Java operation. I suspect I am confusing with Hibernate object life-cycle here.

Please let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: As per code, I do not see any issues with Hibernate. Try to print the values returned by `getCarByVehicleAndType` method and see if the values are correct.

Comment: Why is the list type in `constructVehicleDTO` isn't match ? You r creating list of `List<CustomDTO>` type & returning `List<CustomVehicleDTO>`. Why this is so ?

Comment: Sorry OOS thats a mistake.. I tried to simplify the naming to avoid confusion in question

Comment: Can u show the values returned by `getCarByVehicleAndType(vehicleId, auto.getAutoTypeId()` function & how did u give a call to `constructVehicleDTO(long vehicleId)` ?

Comment: how are you displaying the values? Primefaces iteration?